# WebAudio crashes iPad's Home button

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

I tried SoundJS and also Howler JS on iPad. Both use WebAudio to playback sound. It works perfectly fine in browser, however, if I add it to home screen and run from home screen as a web app, once I play a sound, or sometimes after playing sounds for a while, my home button crashes and doesn't work anymore. Whole app works fine, without any slowness in performance, but Home button doesn't work anymore. The only way is to force shut down, that takes ages to restart. Has anyone had this problem before?

Thanks,
Vladas

Answer (score 1):

The SoundJS team has tracked this issue down to the web app entering full screen mode using:

`<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />`

A bug was reported to apple (reference #15133492).

Currently we have no work around except not entering full screen mode.